# How to speed this python loop up?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm calling this function 'detection_bbox' from while loop

```
def search_layer(detection):
    center_x, center_y, w, h = (detection[0:4] * np.array([width, height, width, height])).astype('int')
    x = int(center_x - w / 2)
    y = int(center_y - h / 2)
    return [x, y, int(w), int(h)]

def detection_bbox(layer_outputs):
    b_boxes = []
    for l_output in layer_outputs:
        b_boxes.extend([search_layer(detect) for detect in l_output if detect[5] > 0.5])
    return b_boxes
```

and I'm trying to run it on 1.2 GHz CPU. l_output has about 5000 elements so it is slowing my application a lot. How can I speed this up?

Comment: Please update your question to include a [mcve].  We have no idea what `search_layer` does, for example.

Answer (score 0):

`search_layer` must be your bottleneck as everything else should be very quick, so:

1. Optimise `search_layer`
2. Only call `search_layer` for those elements where `detect[5]>0` - cutting your search space down and
3. Only run `search_layer` once for those elements.

```
def detection_bbox(layer_outputs):

    b_boxes = []
    valid_outputs = [l for l in layer_outputs if l[5] > 0]

    for output in valid_outputs:
        detect = search_layer(output)
        if detect:
            b_boxes.extend(detect)

    return b_boxes
```